# GAE Python Data Moddeling/querying: property of referenced entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a scenario simmilar to this and I'm trying to find the best/most common solution:

```python
class Car(db.Model):
  peopleCapacity = db.IntegerProperty()

class Wheel(db.Model):
  car = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=Car, collection_name='wheels')
  diameter = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I want the results of this kind of query:

```python
smallWheelsForBigCars = db.GqlQuery(
  'SELECT * FROM Wheel WHERE diameter < 10 AND car.peopleCapacity > 6'        
)
# returns 0 entities as properties like 'car.peopleCapacity' are apparently not supported
```

Some (hacky) solutions I have considered:

- Do the constraints for Wheel and Car separately and manually check for intersections (slow!)
- Store a copy of car.peopleCapacity in Wheel by using a computedProperty. (bad, as I need to update all wheels attached to the car when the car's peopleCapacity changes. And yes, in my actual case "peopleCapacity" would change)

My two quetions are:
Why does car.peopleCapacity not work in queries?
Are there any better approaches to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusions are correct, the datastore doesn't have sub property query ability (you can achieve that using StructureProperty but not the way you are looking for).
You should denormalize your model and put everything in on big entity, it will be a pain to update but will be easier and faster to retrive results.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the terms 'denormalization'. Are you suggesting doing it like my second suggestion or putting it all in _one_ entity?